# IllegalArgumentException when setting public member

Tags: java, reflection

I've been playing around with reflection in Java... and I'm a little bit baffled.

I was hoping that the program below would allow me to change the value of a public member variable within a class. However, I receive an IllegalArgumentException. Any ideas?

```
public class ColinTest {

    public String msg = "fail";

    public ColinTest() { }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        ColinTest test = new ColinTest();
        Class c = test.getClass();
        Field[] decfields = c.getDeclaredFields();
        decfields[0].set("msg", "success");

        System.out.println(ColinTest.msg)
    }
}
```

I receive this message -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:656)
    at ColinTest.main(ColinTest.java:44)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first argument of the [`Field.set`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) method should be the object which you are reflecting on.

```
decfields[0].set("msg", "success");
```

Should read:

```
decfields[0].set(test, "success");
```

Furthermore, the final `System.out.println` call should refer to the `test` object rather than the class `ColinTest`, as I presume the intention is to output the contents of the `test.msg` field.

**Update**

As pointed out by [toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919962/illegalargumentexception-when-setting-public-member/919986#919986) and [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919962/illegalargumentexception-when-setting-public-member/919985#919985), the [`Class.getDeclaredField`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField(java.lang.String)) method can be used to specify the name of the field in order to retrieve it:

```
Field msgField = test.getClass().getDeclaredField("msg");

// or alternatively:

Field msgField = ColinTest.class.getDeclaredField("msg");
```

Then, the `set` method of the `msgField` can be invoked as:

```
msgField.set(test, "success");
```

This way has its benefit, as already pointed out by toolkit, if there are more fields added to the object, the order of the fields that are returned by `Class.getDeclaredFields` may not necessarily return the field `msg` as the first element of the array. Depending on the order of the returned array to be a certain way may cause problems when changes are made to the class.

Therefore, it would probably be a better idea to use `getDeclaredField` and declare the name of the desired field.

Comment: Take care using `decFields[0]` if you plan to add more fields in the future!

Answer (score 2):

The first arg to set() should be the object whose field you are changing... namely test.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure the code you post actually compiles (you want `test.msg`, not `ColinTest.msg`).

You may also consider using a newer version of Java, which could provide a more specific error message:

```
% java ColinTest
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field ColinTest.msg to java.lang.String
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:657)
    at ColinTest.main(ColinTest.java:13)
```

which would probably have led you to the solution others have posted.

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling `getDeclaredFields`, each array element will contain a `Field` object that represents a field on the class, no on an an instantiated object.

That's why you have to specify the object on which you want to set that field, when using the setter:

```
ColinTest test = new ColinTest();
Field msgfield = ColinTest.class.getDeclaredField("msg");
msgField.set(test, "success");
```

Comment: Your first arg should be test, not c.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that, too, right after posting, so I fixed it in an edit right away ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is:

```
Field msgField = c.getDeclaredField("msg");
msgField.set(test, "Success");
```

Take care using `decfields[0]` since you may get not get what you expected when you add a second field to your class (you are not checking that `decfields[0]` corresponds to the `msg` field)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled accros this page, because weirdly, I can not sets public string field in my class. The code will add new row in ArrayList in each for loop. The problem is, I put instantiation code of new object (using reflection that is) only once, outside the inner for.

```
private ArrayList processDataSetResultSetAsArrayList(ResultSet resultSet, String fqnModel) {
    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();

    try {
        ResultSetMetaData metaData;
        int nColoumn;
        String columnName;
        String fieldValue;
        Field field;
        Object modelInstance;

        metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        nColoumn = metaData.getColumnCount();
        resultSet.beforeFirst();
        Class modelClass = Class.forName(fqnModel);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            modelInstance = modelClass.newInstance();
            for (int i = 1; i <= nColoumn; i++) {
                columnName = metaData.getColumnName(i);
                field = modelInstance.getClass().getDeclaredField(columnName);
                fieldValue = resultSet.getString(i);
                field.set(modelInstance, fieldValue);
            }
            result.add(modelInstance);
        }            
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Inspect that now I move the Class.forName(fqnModel) outside the while loop. Because surely we only need to create Class object only once. But then, before each for loop, I create a model object that eventually will be added in a ArrayList.

To be clear, this is my BiroModel class look like:

```
public class BiroModel extends Model {
public String idbiro = "";
public String biro = "";

public BiroModel() {
}

public BiroModel(String table, String pkField) {
    super(table, pkField);
    fqn = BiroModel.class.getName();

}

public String getBiro() {
    return biro;
}

public void setBiro(String biro) {
    this.biro = biro;
}

public String getIdbiro() {
    return idbiro;
}

public void setIdbiro(String idbiro) {
    this.idbiro = idbiro;
}
```

}

I create a convention here, that all field object should be declared public. But, because I need EL syntax, I still need to create getter/setter for this public field.